# Create a remote private registry

Tags: registry, docker, centos6, remote-registry

We are fairly new to docker but have been able to install docker on CentOS 6.4, created images, generated containers, and even created a private local registry.

Our question is in regards to the local registry. Well... actually... regarding a remote registry.  We want to be able to create the registry on a separate server and not have everything in one place.  We installed docker on another VM and have it running, but have had trouble finding documentation on how to access the registry remotely.

Just looking for some direction or url that will show how a remote registry would work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Docker Registry](https://github.com/docker/docker-registryhttps://github.com/docker/docker-registry) repo - it's a separate project to docker.

Their README.md should be enough to get you started.

Comment: We actually found site that might give the information we needed:

http://cloudcounselor.com/2014/01/07/docker-private-registry-on-centos-rhel-6-5/

It requires installing python, git, cloning docker-registry.git, etc.  We will check it against the README you listed and post the findings.

Comment: I imagine the README.md of the project you're being instructed to install on that page will have all you need!

Comment: I may be reading this README file wrong, but it does not appear to be creating a private registry just accessing the docker hub.  Our client's network is closed and cannot access external sites.  We must install docker and docker-registry without directly accessing docker-hub.

Basically we can move tar files, rpm's, etc but cannot create them  though direct download.

Comment: You create a VM somewhere on your network, install docker on it, clone the docker-registry repo, change your config file to something like `local` in the config sample, build the docker image (now with your config), run the docker image.

Comment: We ended up rather than creating the registry as a docker image but as a service running standalone on the VM (service docker-registry start).  We are now able to tag/push/pull from the VM containing docker.  It was actually much faster and easier than configuring as a docker image.

We downloaded all the required RPMS, installed them, and started the registry.

Comment: @user3897489 You did exactly what I need to do. Can you be a bit more specific on that? Perhaps a quick step by step..

Answer (score 0):

Our network would not allow us to access the internet to download RPMs. We determined the RPMs required to install docker-registry, downloaded them, placed them in a shell script in the order necessary to remove dependency issues, installed the RPMs and then start the service -- "service docker-registry start".

This does not create the registry as a docker image but as a standalone service -- not even sure why people seem to think having the registry as a docker image is preferable... seems to add an additional layer of unnecessary abstraction.

Below is the shell script with the list of RPMs in the "correct" order.  Once executed, run "service docker-registry start".

```
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-setuptools-0.6.10-3.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-pip-1.3.1-4.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh --force --nodeps glibc-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh --force glibc-common-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh mpfr-2.4.1-6.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh ppl-0.10.2-11.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh kernel-headers-2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh glibc-headers-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh glibc-devel-2.12-1.132.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libgomp-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh cloog-ppl-0.15.7-1.2.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh cpp-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libyaml-0.1.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh PyYAML-3.10-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libevent-1.4.13-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-babel-0.9.4-5.1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-greenlet-0.4.2-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-gevent-0.13.8-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-gunicorn-18.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-jinja2-2.2.1-2.el6_5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-markupsafe-0.9.2-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-jinja2-26-2.6-3.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-werkzeug-0.8.3-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-flask-0.9-7.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-backports-1.0-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-backports-ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-ordereddict-1.1-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-six-1.7.3-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-urllib3-1.5-7.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-chardet-2.0.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-requests-1.1.0-4.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-redis-2.0.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-blinker-1.1-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-simplejson-2.0.9-3.1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh pyliblzma-0.5.3-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-backports-lzma-0.0.2-5.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh gcc-4.4.7-4.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh --force --nodeps python-lxml-2.2.3-1.1.el6.x86_64.rpm

rpm -ivh python-prettytable-0.7.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-httplib2-0.7.7-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-sqlalchemy-0.5.5-3.el6_2.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-argparse-1.2.1-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-keystoneclient-0.2.0-3.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-importlib-1.0.2-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-jsonschema-2.3.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-warlock-0.4.0-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh python-boto-2.27.0-1.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh pyOpenSSL-0.10-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-glanceclient-0.8.0-2.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh redis-2.4.10-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python-rsa-3.1.1-5.el6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh docker-registry-0.7.1-2.el6.noarch.rpm
```